# jquery nested function access

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

How can I access the test2() function outer either in onclick , as shown in the  plain function, wrapped in parenthesis to tell the runtime to return the function to the parent scope, once it's returned the function is executed using line 4, maybe reading through these steps will help.

```
<p onclick='test().test2()'> some text </p>; 

<script>

  //the below declaration will not change 
  var jQuery = 'Hi';
  (function ($) { 
    function test(){
      function test2(){
        alert('text')
      }
      alert($)
    } 
    console.log($);
    test().test2()
  })(jQuery)

</script>
```

Comment: A simple suggestion to look in the docs for basics of javascript, especially OOP in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access `test2` if you declare the function in the same scope as where you want the to access the function. In this case it means you need to declare the function in the outer scope.

You can do so by setting a variable in the outer scope like this:

```
var test2;
 var jQuery = 'Hi';
  (function ($) { 
    function test(){
      test2 = function(){
        alert('text')
      }
      alert($)
    } 
    console.log($);
    test(); //test needs to be called first to define test2.
    test2();
  })(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked twice and this works:

```
    var jQuery = 'Hi';
    window.test = (function ($) {
        function test(){
            this.test2 = function () {
                alert('text')
            };
            alert($);
            return this;
        }
        console.log($);
        test().test2();

        return test;
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: It's not the best solution for a problem in general, but this code works.

Comment: I checked in Chrome console. I executed code in Chrome console. Then I added 'onclick='test().test2()' to 'body' element of the page. And after clicking I had two alerts ('Hi' and 'text').